# Check if a parameter exists in XSLT before using it

Tags: xml, xslt, altova

I am using XPATH to work out if my parameter $test exists.
I am using the XPATH builder in ALtova Stylevision and thought I could use something like
`exists ( $blah)` or `exists ( string($blah) )`
But this ends with

`" Undefined variable in expression test="exists(  string( $blah)  )""`

The issue is that sometimes the parameter will exist, and sometimes it won't. I don't want to have to hardcode in a blank parameter!

Is there a way I can say "Check if the parameter XXXX exists" before I use it? It's frustrating as I know how to do this in pretty much every other programming language

Parameter defined:

`<xsl:param name="blah"> some text </xsl:param>`

These parameters are read in from a seperate file "parameters.xslt". This file may or may not exist, depending on the scenario. I need to check the param actually exists before I attempt to use it.

Answer (score 4):

If you’ve declared the parameter, it exists. What you want to know is, [does it have a value?](http://www.stylusstudio.com/xsllist/199911/post30020.html)

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="not($blah)">$blah wasn’t passed in</xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>$blah was passed in</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Comment: The issue is that the parameters are dragged in from a parameters file "Parameters.xslt". Sometimes, depending on the scenario, this file won't be needed. So what I need to do is check if the parameter actually exists/been created.9Is this even possible?) On the plus side, the "NOT()" works ok for the cases where the parameter does exist.

Comment: Ah. No, I don’t believe there’s a way to check on a parameter without knowing whether it exists. Are you conditionally adding an `<xsl:import/>` or `<xsl:include/>`? If so, what about including something like `<xsl:variable name='included-parameters' select='true()'/>` when Parameters.xslt is included, and `<xsl:variable name='included-parameters' select='false()'/>` when it hasn’t been?

Comment: And when I say “conditionally adding”, I mean that this must be happening when you are *generating* a stylesheet, right? Because I believe `import`/`include` can only be direct children of `stylesheet`, not something like an `if`.

Comment: Hmm, I like that idea. The file is imported with `<xsl:import/>` but done through Stylevision (Not sure if its done dynamically or not though), so I'm going to have to search for a way to edit the importing first :)

Comment: Seems I will have to create a global file with blank parameters I think! Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

Basically, if you are writing XSLT then you are expected to know what variables have been declared. You're trying to work with some kind of development model where people writing different modules of the stylesheet don't have full knowledge of each other's code, and XSLT isn't designed to work with that model.

XSLT is hardly unique in this: you won't find anything in a Java method that allows the writer of the method to ask "how many arguments have been supplied by the caller?". If insufficient arguments have been supplied, the code simply won't compile.